# Using select last_insert_id to generate unique ids

Tags: php, mysql, last-insert-id

After reading through possible options here on Stackoverflow, I don't see an answer for the exact case I'm considering...

CASE: I have a php system that auto-generates mysql-connected templates.

In order for the system to work, I need each generated template to have a unique 6-digit integer assigned upon it's creation.  Instead of messing with randomizers, etc...

A) could I simply create a table in the database called 'pageid', with int(11) / unique / autoincrement with starting value 100000, and then during the template creation process, simply perform an insert on this table, and then a 'select last_insert_id()' to pull the last value, which is then injected into the template as it's created? (in otherwords, the table's only function is to generate and spit back the last unique id).

B) if so, are there any issues I should be concerned about using this method? (aside from the fact that it means a limit of only 899,999 templates can be generated - which is not an issue in this case).

Any thoughts or better methods appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > could I simply create a table in the database called 'pageid', with int(11) / unique / autoincrement with starting value 100000, and then during the template creation process, simply perform an insert on this table, and then a 'select last_insert_id()' to pull the last value, which is then injected into the template as it's created? (in otherwords, the table's only function is to generate and spit back the last unique id).

   Yes:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE pages (
     pageid MEDIUMINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
   ) AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000;
   ```

   Note that I am using `MEDIUMINT(6)` as it requires 1 byte less storage than `INT` and has a more appropriate display width for your needs.
2. > if so, are there any issues I should be concerned about using this method? (aside from the fact that it means a limit of only 899,999 templates can be generated - which is not an issue in this case).

   You could instead just have that column in your `templates` table, and have the `id` automatically assigned whenever a new record is inserted.

Comment: (Accidently hit enter) ... For #2, it's a unique system in that the database entries are created from the templates AFTER template creation - so that's why a separate table would be a better fit in this case. For #1, as I haven't used a table for this purpose before, is there a better way than having the unique id and an arbitrary column, into which I am inserting arbitrary data, just for the purpose of +1'ing the autoincrement?  THANKS

Comment: @Soyo: You don't need an arbitrary column: using my example above, all you need do is `INSERT INTO pages VALUES (NULL)`.